TikZ Euclide [new] option
I am trying to use tkz-euclide package, in particular, I tried compiling the following codes from the manual:
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]

  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,5/0/B,1/4/C}

  \tkzDefTriangleCenter[centroid](A,B,C)

  \tkzGetPoint{G}

  \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)

  \tkzDrawLines[add = 0 and 2/3,new](A,G B,G C,G)

  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,G)

  \tkzLabelPoint(G){$G$}

\end{tikzpicture}

This should generate a triangle with its centroid marked as G. But when I try to compile it, I get the error message: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/new'...
I suppose it has to do with the line "\tkzDrawLines[add = 0 and 2/3,new](A,G B,G C,G)
", and indeed, when I remove "new" in the bracket, next to 2/3, it complies properly (seemingly so).
So my questions: (1) Why do I get these error messages, (2) What does "new" do in the command, and is it okay to omit it as I did?

new is a style, you should define it before using it.
See Section "5. About this documentation and the examples" of the package documentation.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tkzSetUpStyle[color=orange,line width=.2pt]{new}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,5/0/B,1/4/C}
  \tkzDefTriangleCenter[centroid](A,B,C)
  \tkzGetPoint{G}
  \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
  \tkzDrawLines[add = 0 and 2/3,new](A,G B,G C,G)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,G)
  \tkzLabelPoint(G){$G$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


